# How to filter a column in Excel

Tags: excel, filter, multiple-columns

Let's say there are two columns. 1st column is ID, 2nd column is purchase.
I want to filter the 1st (ID) column for distinct values only but if the ID contains a distinct value in purchase I want to keep that ID value.

For example:

```
ID      Purchase
01      food
01      food
01      water
01      electricity 
02      water 
02      candy
02     water
02     juice
```

Using Excel's Advanced Sort & Filter tool under Data I can obtain all distinct values of ID. Such that I will only return:

```
01 food 
02 water
```

But I would like to return all distinct IDs with distinct purchases. Such as:

```
01 food
01 water 
01 electricity 
02 water 
02 candy 
02 juice
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Use remove duplicates on the data tab and include both columns.

Comment: When I use Advanced Filter on that data I get the desired result, how exactly are you applying the filter?

Comment: Thank you both! The solution was that I was only selecting the ID column and not the Purchase column as well when applying the Advanced Filter.

Answer (score 0):

Select both columns when applying the Advanced Filter for Unique values.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).